# Emacs: clean up numbered lists with more than 9 lines

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

Is there a setting in Emacs that will automatically re-align numbered lists that go beyond 9 lines in length? For example, the default behavior gives me this:

```
1. Item one
2. Item two
3. Item three
4. Item four
5. Item five
6. Item six
7. Item seven
8. Item eight
9. Item nine
10. Oops! <-- notice the indent
```

What I would like to see is something like this:

```
 1. Item one
 2. Item two
 3. Item three
 4. Item four
 5. Item five
 6. Item six
 7. Item seven
 8. Item eight
 9. Item nine
10. item ten
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Since you used the org-mode tag, I believe that in that mode all items in the same list must have the the same indentation. See the [org-mode plain lists documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Plain-lists.html) where it says "In particular, if an ordered list reaches number ‘10.’, then the 2–digit numbers must be written left-aligned with the other numbers in the list."

Comment: Thanks Steve. I must be doing something wrong then. I am using org-mode. But the results I get are as above (first example)...

Comment: That's what I mean: your first example is what org-mode requires, i.e., I don't believe your second example will work because its indentation doesn't fit the requirements.

Comment: This question inspired me to ask [a related question on the Emacs Stack Exchange site](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/text-alignment-in-org-mode-numbered-lists).  Although you might not be able to get the digits to align this way, you *can* zero-pad them so that it's 01, 02, 03, ..., 10 -- see the solution there.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** As has been pointed out by commenters, this solution will indent the list as requested, but in doing so will break org-mode functionality. Since org-mode requires lists to not be indented in this manner, there is no way to have both.

This can do it:

```
(defun align-line-numbers (front back)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp front back "^\\([0-9]+\\)" -1 0 t))
```

You can then mark the region and call the function to indent all numbers.

```
9. Item nine
10. Oops!
100. foo
1000. bar
```

becomes

```
   9. Item nine
  10. Oops!
 100. foo
1000. bar
```

If it's always the whole buffer,

```
(defun align-line-numbers nil 
  (interactive)
  (align-regexp (point-min) (point-max) "^\\([0-9]+\\)" -1 0 t))
```

Comment: That solution does align the numbers as requested, but it unfortunately breaks the functionality of the list.  For example: try entering another list item inside it, or hit `C-c C-c` -- `org-mode` will renumber the list.

Comment: Oh, org-mode. I should have read the tags and comments, I suppose; yes, in that case it's not possible. Er...is it good etiquette to leave the answer now, or do I remove it? It might be useful for someone down the line, I think, albeit not in the context of org-mode.

Comment: I'd lean towards leaving it here but marking it as a partial solution -- it does what OP wants if OP is not going to fiddle with the list after aligning it.